# Database.Query Variable Does Not Exist

Tags: lightning-aura-components, query, dynamic-soql, database

How can I get the field results from a dynamic database query to be available to be put into a list? Here is the code I have:

```
//Query on the destinationObjectFieldName results
    List<sObject> desinationObjectList =
        Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM ' + destinationObject + 'WHERE Id IN :relJunctionObjects' );
    System.debug('desinationObjectList List contains: ' + desinationObjectList);

    //Add the results into the RelatedObject list
    for(sObject s: desinationObjectList) {
        pickListValuesList.add(new RelatedObject(s.Id,s.Name));
    }
```

Yet I get the error

> Variable does not exist: Name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only field you can directly retrieve from an sObject is Id. All other fields must be referenced dynamically:

```
    pickListValuesList.add(new RelatedObject(s.Id,(String)s.get('Name')));
```

This is due to the fact that the compiler must be able to verify that the field exists, which it cannot do for Name without a concrete sObject type (e.g. Account). Note that a few objects do not have a Name field, so if you use this code on some specific objects, expect a QueryException.